# relation between matrix multiplication and Hadamard product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-equations, hadamard-product

Let $\circ$ denote the Hadamard product, i.e. entry-wise multiplication. Suppose we have 4 vectors $\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z}$ and $ \vec{t}$ be in $\mathbb{Z}^m$ such that
$$
\vec{x}\circ\vec{y}=\vec{z}\circ\vec{t}
$$
Let $A\in\mathbb{Z}^{n\times m}$ be a matrix ($m>n$) that can be multiplied by $\vec{x}$ (or any other of the above mentioned vectors) on the right. Does exist any kind of non-trivial function $f$ (for example not the constant functions) such that
$$
f(A\vec{x}, A\vec{y})=f(A\vec{z}, A\vec{t})
$$
or is there a way to prove that such a function $f$ cannot exist (or has to be constant)?

Thank you!

EDIT: I am also interested if it is possible to obtain such a function $f$ when we assume some kind of restrictions on the vectors $\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z}$ and $\vec{t}$.

EDIT2: It is not a problem if the function $f$ depends onthe matrix $A$ used.

Comment: $x,y,z,t$ are fixed vectors or the identity must hold for all possible $x,y,z,t$  ?

Comment: The best case scenario would be to find some function $f$ (which can depend on $A$) that works for **all** vectors $\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z}$ and $\vec{t}$.

Comment: But even if you can find some function $f$ that only works with vectors that satisfy some further restrictions would be interesting for me.

Comment: sorry I should have added it: $A\in\mathbb{Z}^{n\times m}$ is a rectangular matrix ($m>n$) hence not invertible.